# ansible defining variable for timestamp

Tags: ansible

I am having troubles when setting a variable with a timestamp in ansible to use it through my playbook.
What I want to achieve is to have the release folder name in two servers and a new db tagged with the same timestamp.

I am defining these variables in a file called common.yml in /ansibleproject/vars/.

```
timestamp: "{{lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')}}"
release_name: '{{ repo_tag }}_{{timestamp}}'
new_db_name: '{{release_name}}'
```

Then, on a task file I am creating the dirs like this:

```
- name: "Create new release folder"
  file: path={{new_release_path}} state=directory mode=2775 owner=deployment group=deployment
  become: yes
```

And on a separate task file I am creating the db like this:

```
- name: "Prepare db user rights"
  shell: echo "CREATE DATABASE \`{{new_db_name}}\` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; " > db_create.sql
  when: inventory_hostname ==  groups['app'][0]

- name: "Create new database for new release"
  shell: mysql -h {{mysql_server}} -u{{mysql_username}} -p{{mysql_password}} < db_create.sql
  when: inventory_hostname ==  groups['app'][0]
```

The folder is created with the same timestamp on the two servers I am deploying:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 deployment deployment 4096 Mar 14 16:36 test_20170314173640Z/
```

but the db name has a different timestamp.

```
mysql> show databases;
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| information_schema                                            |
| dummy                                                         |
| mysql                                                         |
| performance_schema                                            |
| test_20170314173819Z                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I was reading about "set_fact" to set a timestamp, but that seems to work on a host basis.

Is there any way to have it consistent on both servers and on the db?

Regards,

Answer (score 8):

This is expected behaviour, because variables are templated when used, but not when "defined" (they are not defined actually).
So `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ` is executed for each task (at different time of cause).

If you need consistency, use `set_fact` to make persistent fact:

```
- set_fact:
    timestamp: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ') }}"
```

After this `timestamp` is a plain string with result of pipe, and not Jinja expression as it is in your case.

You can make this fact for every host or only for `localhost` and access it as `hostvars['localhost'].timestamp` from other hosts.

Comment: Good idea about setting it once, and using it from there!

Comment: Thanks for the anwser.
I was able to achieve what I wanted with a fact for localhost.  

This is what I did:  
site.yml
`- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Getting current timestamp"
      set_fact:
        timestamp_fact: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ') }}"`  

vars/common.yml  
`timestamp: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].timestamp_fact }}"`  

I am not sure if it is redundant to "define" timestamp again in the vars file, but it makes it easier to access it later in the tasks files with {{timestamp}}

Comment: this does not work ... with ansible v2.5.5, even with set_fact the timestamp is still being updated